# JNI Error caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception, executable-jar

my Spring Boot App that I built with maven starts in intelliJ and does as intended, but when I run the .jar it gives me this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/ITemplateResolver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: which version of Spring-boot you are using?